# Porque el RecyclerView no se actualiza

Tags: android

Hola resulta que tengo un Recycler que se alimenta de un servidror con un usuario e imagen todo anda bien cuando lo ejecute por primera vez, pero cuando inserto mas registros no se actualiza y me toca borrar la cache del telefono y hay si actualiza, supongo que de ahi el nombre Recycler pero como solucionar esto?

```
    Public class UsuariosImagenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsuariosImagenAdapter.UsuariosHolder>{

    List<Usuario> listaUsuarios;

    public UsuariosImagenAdapter(List<Usuario> listaUsuarios) {
        this.listaUsuarios = listaUsuarios;
    }

    @Override
    public UsuariosHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View vista= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.usuarios_list_image,parent,false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        vista.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new UsuariosHolder(vista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UsuariosHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtDocumento.setText(listaUsuarios.get(position).getDocumento().toString());
        holder.txtNombre.setText(listaUsuarios.get(position).getNombre().toString());
        holder.txtProfesion.setText(listaUsuarios.get(position).getProfesion().toString());

        if (listaUsuarios.get(position).getImagen()!=null){
            holder.imagen.setImageBitmap(listaUsuarios.get(position).getImagen());
        }else{
            holder.imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_base);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaUsuarios.size();
    }

    public class UsuariosHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView txtDocumento,txtNombre,txtProfesion;
        ImageView imagen;

        public UsuariosHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtDocumento= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idDocumento);
            txtNombre= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idNombre);
            txtProfesion= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idProfesion);
            imagen=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagen);
        }
    }
}
```

**aqui el otro codigo donde implemento lo del recycler**

```
    public class ConsutarListausuarioImagenFragment extends Fragment
        implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>,Response.ErrorListener{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    RecyclerView recyclerUsuarios;
    ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios;

    ProgressDialog dialog;

   // RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;


    public ConsutarListausuarioImagenFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ConsutarListausuarioImagenFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ConsutarListausuarioImagenFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ConsutarListausuarioImagenFragment fragment = new ConsutarListausuarioImagenFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consutar_listausuario_imagen, container, false);;

        listaUsuarios=new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerUsuarios = (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.idRecyclerImagen);
        recyclerUsuarios.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
        recyclerUsuarios.setHasFixedSize(true);

       // request= Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        cargarWebService();

        return vista;
    }

    private void cargarWebService() {

        dialog=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        dialog.setMessage("Consultando Imagenes");
        dialog.show();

        String ip=getString(R.string.ip);

        String url=ip+"/ejemploBDRemotaimg/wsJSONConsultarListaImagenes.php";
        jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
       // request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Usuario usuario=null;

        JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("usuario");

        try {

            for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                usuario=new Usuario();
                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(i);

                usuario.setDocumento(jsonObject.optInt("documento"));
                usuario.setNombre(jsonObject.optString("nombre"));
                usuario.setProfesion(jsonObject.optString("profesion"));
                usuario.setDato(jsonObject.optString("imagen"));
                listaUsuarios.add(usuario);
            }
            dialog.hide();
            UsuariosImagenAdapter adapter=new UsuariosImagenAdapter(listaUsuarios);
            recyclerUsuarios.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha podido establecer conexión con el servidor" +
                    " "+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }




    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código donde implementas el recyclerView.

Comment: Es importante agregues la parte donde configuras el adapter a tu listado y donde agregas los datos como comenta David.

Comment: ok ya agregue el codigo

Comment: Gracias @juanperez agregamos una respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Cuando actualices los datos , debes asegurar llamar el método [**notifyDataSetChanged();**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

> [**notifyDataSetChanged();**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) Notifica a cualquier observador
>   registrado que el los datos han cambiado.

Lo realizarías de esta forma dentro de tu método `onResponse()` que es el que determina la respuesta al realizar una nueva petición de datos, únicamente te falta agregar  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`:

```
 @Override
   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        ...
        ...
        UsuariosImagenAdapter adapter=new UsuariosImagenAdapter(listaUsuarios);
        recyclerUsuarios.setAdapter(adapter);
        //actualiza datos en Adapter.
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        ...
        ...
   }
```

Comment: El notifyDataSetChanged no es necesario si previamente está volviendo a setear el adapter recyclerUsuarios.setAdapter

Comment: NO la verdad tampoco funciona si teniendo que eliminar la cache

Comment: ya comprobaste que en verdad listaUsuarios tenga datos diferentes? @juanperez

Comment: si claro inserto a la base de datos elimino modifico y al momento de abrir el activity donde se muestran los datos no los actualiza entonces voy borro el cache de esa aplicacion y hay si los muestra